# Windows Browser DST Bug prior to 2007

Tags: javascript, windows, dst

Windows browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox) are not respecting the old US daylight saving time rules for dates prior to 2007.  Using a machine set to Eastern Time, the following javascript call returns an incorrect time:

```
(new Date("03/15/1993")).toGMTString();
```

returns:

```
Mon, 15 Mar 1993 04:00:00 GMT <-- Incorrect
```

should be:

```
Mon, 15 Mar 1993 05:00:00 GMT <-- Correct
```

Chrome and Firefox for OSX return the correct value so it appears to be an issue with browsers making a Windows API call.

The DST rule changes are:

- Prior to 2007: 1st Sunday in April until Last Sunday in October

- After 2007: 2nd Sunday in March until 1st Sunday in November

It appears that Windows is applying the current rules for dates prior to 2007.  In my case, I have a Javascript framework that communicates with our server side (Java) framework using full GMT time.  Java is applying the CORRECT rules, so in the case of the above date, the server is interpreting the incorrectly submitted time March 14th 1993.

Same submission from all browsers in OSX is working correctly.

Has anyone experienced anything like this or know of any workaround?

Comment: Note that only Windows Vista onwards has historical DST support, and then also only for some areas/updates.

Comment: I found exactly the same issue. Did you find any fix for it?